# UrlGenerator::generate() triggers deprecation notice

Tags: symfony, deprecated

I'm getting this deprecation error, but I can't figure out where it is coming from. I am using Symfony 2.8.2 and CMF Routing 1.3.

This is the error:

```
The hardcoded value you are using for the $referenceType argument of the Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator::generate method is deprecated since version 2.8 and will not be supported anymore in 3.0. Use the constants defined in the UrlGeneratorInterface instead.  Hide stack trace

UrlGenerator::doGenerate() (called from appDevUrlGenerator.php at line 95)
appDevUrlGenerator::generate() (called from classes.php at line 1284)
Router::generate() (called from ChainRouter.php at line 231)
ChainRouter::generate() (called from WebDebugToolbarListener.php at line 68)
WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse() call_user_func() (called from WrappedListener.php at line 61)
WrappedListener::__invoke() call_user_func() (called from classes.php at line 1853)
EventDispatcher::doDispatch() (called from classes.php at line 1771)
EventDispatcher::dispatch() (called from TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 132)
TraceableEventDispatcher::dispatch() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 179)
HttpKernel::filterResponse() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 161)
HttpKernel::handleRaw() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 62)
HttpKernel::handle() (called from ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69)
ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() (called from Kernel.php at line 185)
Kernel::handle() (called from app_dev.php at line 30)
require() (called from router_dev.php at line 40)
```

From my code I don't call doGenerate() anywhere. Maybe the Symfony CMF routing component is calling to somewhere? Where should I look for this error?

Comment: You should search for `router->generate(` calls where the third argument is not a constant of UrlGeneratorInterface (maybe it is in the vendor codebase). Ohh and look https://github.com/symfony-cmf/Routing/blob/1.3.0/ChainRouter.php#L214 ... the default value is wrong so if you do not give the 3rd argument every time it will trigger a deprecation notice. It was fixed by [#158](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/Routing/pull/158), but not realesd in a stable version (only RC), itt will be in 1.4 when it comes out.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. After the 1.4 release the deprecation warning should go away then. Can you submit your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should search for router->generate( calls where the third argument is not a constant of UrlGeneratorInterface (maybe it is in the vendor codebase). Ohh and look http://github.com/symfony-cmf/Routing/blob/1.3.0/ChainRouter.php#L214 ... the default value is wrong so if you do not give the 3rd argument every time it will trigger a deprecation notice. It was fixed by [#158](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/Routing/pull/158), but not realesd in a stable version (only RC), itt will be in 1.4 when it comes out.